# Clearing Modal Data When User Clicks "Save"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a multi-part modal wizard that uses Bootstrap and jQuery. When the user gets to part 3 of the modal, and clicks "save" I want to wipe the data - because right now when I re-open the modal, it re-loads to the 3rd part, rather than restarting from step 1, which is what it should do.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="repeat-every-div">
      <label>Repeat Every</label>
      <input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scheduleModal">
    </div>

    <div id="scheduleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Recurring Job Steps</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="myWizard">

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="step1">

                <div class="well">

                  <label>Recurring Interval</label>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="daily" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Daily</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="weekly" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Weekly</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="monthly" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Monthly</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#step2">Continue</a> -->
                <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#weeklyOptions" data-toggle="tab" data-step="2">Continue</a>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="tab-pane fade" id="weekly-options"> -->
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="weeklyOptions">
                <div class="well">
                  <label>Day of the Week</label>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="monday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Monday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="tuesday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Tuesday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="wednesday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Wednesday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="thursday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Thursday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="friday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Friday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="saturday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Saturday</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="sunday" name="materialExampleRadios">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Sunday</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="btn btn-default next" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" data-step="3">Continue</a>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="step3">
                <div class="md-form mx-5 my-5">
                  <input type="time" id="inputMDEx1" class="form-control">
                  <label for="inputMDEx1">Choose your time</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="save-recurring-job">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is what I'm calling when the user clicks the "save" button:

```
$("#save-recurring-job").click(
  function (event) {
    $("#scheduleModal").removeData();
  }
);
```

As I mentioned, at present this isn't working. When I re-open the modal, part 3 reloads with the last entered data still there. What do I need to do here to clear all data when the user clicks "save"?

Comment: is the html within a form?

Comment: If you mean, is it within <form> tags, the answer is no.

Comment: yes if you use a form tag, there's a reset function you can call on it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: Interesting. That worked to clear the data from part 3, but it still re-loaded part 3, rather than starting from step 1, as it should.

Comment: is #step3 in the url when you re-open?

Comment: This is what I click to re-open the modal:
`<input type="text" class="job-repeat-every form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scheduleModal">` The url at that time is: `http://localhost:3001`

Comment: my point is you're using href="#step3" to navigate to that tab, which should change the url. wondering if that's why it stays there when you reopen

Comment: Right, but I checked and step3 is not part of the url that's showing. See my appended comment.

Comment: ah I see, ok posted an answer below that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the data you can wrap it in a `<form>` tag and call the [form reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) function to return to the initial state.

As for the active tab, looks like it uses an `active` class, so you can add that class to the first and remove from any others on close (or open) via `classList.add`/`classList.remove`.

Comment: Getting closer. I now have this: `$("#save-recurring-job").click(
  function (event) {
    console.log('event: ', event);
    document.getElementById('recurring-job-form').reset();
    this.classList.remove('active');
  }
);`

This fixes the issue but creates another one, in that it closes out the entire form section that was open. I don't want that, because there are other form fields the user needs to select. Will have to look into how to handle that.

Comment: do you just need to add active class to the first one again?

Comment: Maybe. Will try that.